# solver for non-convex matrix optimization with convex constraints

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

So here is the problem:

$\max_{D}  ~~ \|A+BD\|$

subject to

$\|D\|<1$ (any norm you like)

where matrices A and B are given.

The cost function is evidently convex as well as the constraint, but I'm looking for the maximum which may occur at the boundary.

What solver do you suggest? or do you have any idea to convex it to a convex optimization?

Note that this is a "matrix" optimization problem.

Comment: So you know very well it is non-convex, but you've tagged it with convex-optimizaiton and convex-analysis?

Comment: My only suggestion is to try $D=\mathop{\textrm{argmin}}_{\|D\|\leq 1} \|A-BD\|$, and use that $D$ as your guess for the maximizer of $\|A+BD\|$. For the right norms (Frobenius, spectral), I think that will work surprisingly well.

Comment: How about this approach: $\|A+BD\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|\|D\|$, but I don't know when the upper bound holds?